# Android - Achieving line break in XML string with String.format()?

Tags: java, android, xml, newline, string-formatting

This is my xml string...

```
<string name="my_string">First line.\nSecond line: %1$s.\nThird line.</string>
```

...which I need to run through String.format without losing the line breaks.

How do I achieve that?

Here is my Java code...

```
String text = String.format(getString(R.string.my_string, "some text");
Spanned html = Html.fromHtml(text, this, null);
textView.setText(html);
```

In the xml file, I have tried using `\n` and `<br />` and actual new lines, but none of them produce line breaks in the textView on the UI.

Comment: What's wrong with `\n`? It's perfect working in my case. I used this string `First line. \n Second line: %1$s.\n Third line.`

Comment: If you wan to load string as Html then you have to use <br/> instead \n and replace '<' with '&lt;' in <br/> like : &lt;br/>.

Comment: \n worked for me when I used it with String.format(String1, String2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this for HTML string:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string name="title">Hello&lt;br /&gt;World!</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: Not required &gt; for ending HTML-escaped string only need &lt;.

Answer (score 0):

For using `<br />`, as its a html tag you must wrap the string in CDATA.
Use this.

```
<string name="my_string"><![CDATA][First line. <br />Second line. <br />Third line.]]</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try to replace '<' with &lt; in HTML-escaped string :

<string name="my_string">First line.&lt;br/>Second line: %1$s.&lt;br/>Third line.</string>
```

More details check this : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html